# Linq Cannot Translate ToShortDateString()

Tags: c#, linq

Can you please tell me how to fix the query below. LINQ was formating my dates as written out example: August 8th 2015. I need 8/8/2015. Every attempt i try gives me a different error message. What am i doing wrong.

```
var orgData = (from d in db.tbl_FormsSubmittedValues
               where d.SiteID == _siteID
               & d.FormID == _formID
               & ((d.tbl_FormsSubmitted.UserID == _userID && _viewOwnOnly) || !_viewOwnOnly)
               & ((_search != "" && d.Value.Contains(_search)) || _search == "")
               select new
               {
                   d.FormSubmissionID,
                   Value = d.ValueDate.HasValue ? d.ValueDate.Value.ToShortDateString(): d.ValueLong != null ? d.ValueLong : d.Value,
                   d.FieldID,
                   d.FormID,
                   d.SiteID,
                   d.tbl_FormsSubmitted,
                   d.tbl_FormsSubmitted.UserID,
               }).ToList();
```

Original Line That was giving me written out date instead of mm/dd/yyyy

```
 Value = d.ValueDate != null ? d.ValueDate.ToString() : d.ValueLong != null ? d.ValueLong : d.Value,
```

Problem Line:

```
Value = d.ValueDate.HasValue ? d.ValueDate.Value.ToShortDateString(): d.ValueLong != null ? d.ValueLong : d.Value,
```

Error:

```
Could not translate expression 'd.ValueDate.Value.ToShortDateString()' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend:

```
Value = d.ValueDate.HasValue ? (d.ValueDate.Value.Day + "/" + d.ValueDate.Value.Month + "/" + d.ValueDate.Value.Year) : (d.ValueLong != null ? d.ValueLong : d.Value),
```

Or doing the toshortstring when displaying the data (If you are using it on a website)

Or even parse the date through javascript using the parsed date (json)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to creating a new anonymous object would be to create a new typed object (e.g. `select new Submission() { ... }`) that exposes a read-only property for rendering a short date.  This may add some overhead for such a simple operation, but it offers some flexibility (you can format more fields later) and performance (any additional query or filter operations are performed against the database instead of in memory).

Or, you could push the work down the pipe to the presentation layer.  Let the code responsible for displaying the data to the user handle converting or displaying the short date and keep your data/business layers lean and open to other interpretations.  This would keep you from having to go back and change the query or modify your POCO to accommodate a change in the preference for date format.  For example, what if you had another person who preferred the date to be shown as YYYY-dd-MM?

Comment: I am sorry I am a  confused by this.  I should create a class using the same properties that i can currently declaring in my current query.  Replace my `new` statement with the new class.  At that point it would cause the query to execute differently?

Comment: No no. I'm highlighting a potential problem based on @psoshmo's answer. There are performance considerations based on the way you write your queries.  When you request `AsEnumerable` or `ToList, you're signalling the framework to execute a query on the database.  If you were to add a Where clause after one of those, you'd filtering the data in memory instead of on the database. That's potentially very expensive. That's what I meant by "any additional query or filter operations". Creating a read-only property saves you from selecting all the data into memory to perform a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Do the formatting outside of the actual sql. Something like:

```
orgData = (from d in db.tbl_FormsSubmittedValues
           where d.SiteID == _siteID
           & d.FormID == _formID
           & ((d.tbl_FormsSubmitted.UserID == _userID && _viewOwnOnly) || !_viewOwnOnly)
           & ((_search != "" && d.Value.Contains(_search)) || _search == "")
           select new {
                       d.FormSubmissionID,
                       Value = d.ValueDate.HasValue ? d.ValueDate.Value: d.ValueLong != null ? d.ValueLong : d.Value,
                       d.FieldID,
                       d.FormID,
                       d.SiteID,
                       d.tbl_FormsSubmitted,
                       d.tbl_FormsSubmitted.UserID
                      }).AsEnumerable() //Using this to get the query to run.
           //Anything after this should not be done on the database side.
           .Select(d => new
           {
               d.FormSubmissionID,
               Value = d.ValueDate.HasValue ? FormatDate(d.ValueDate.Value): d.ValueLong != null ? d.ValueLong : d.Value,
               d.FieldID,
               d.FormID,
               d.SiteID,
               d.tbl_FormsSubmitted,
               d.tbl_FormsSubmitted.UserID,
           }).ToList();


static string FormatDate(DateTime date)
{
    return  date.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

This keeps the formatting out of the actual generated sql.

Comment: You might want to highlight what you actually did to have the formatting happen outside the sql. I nearly missed it and I was looking for it! :)

Comment: I wouldn't do this, because even if you do the where clause, you are pushing all the columns from db.tbl_FormsSubmittedValues. I would go for a performance friendly option.

Comment: @LeandroSoares This is still the right approach, it's just incomplete.  You should project out all of the columns needed in the first select, and then format the raw data in the second.

Comment: @LeandroSoares I see where you are coming from. I am genuinely curious what the performance impact of extra columns is in a large data set

Comment: @psoshmo It means sending all of that data over the network.  If there are a lot of rows and unused columns, that could easily be a lot of data, which could take quite a lot of time to move over the wire.  If there are few unused columns, or few rows returned, then it may not be a concern.

Comment: @psoshmo, If you have a 200 columns table, it will do some impact. I would do this if i needed some custom method to format something or if dealing with multi locale dates. But in this case there is no need to use a method. But most of the time there is always a work around to avoid this.

Comment: @Servy edited to reduce the number of columns. Is this better?

Comment: @psoshmo, yes i was thinking about that. But it isn't clean is it? ok, it's a developer option i think.

Comment: @LeandroSoares There are still benefits to using a method. We do not know if the OP has other queries which also require similar date formatting. if the format changes one day, this means he only needs to change his code in one place. I personally believe it is the "correct" setup, especially if this is to be expanded upon, even though it may seem like overkill at this moment in time

Comment: @psoshmo, i know but i'm not a great fan of this kind of approaches when talking about little things. I'm working in a big ass project and in some time i needed to change something like this in all over the project (It was a change from ToShortDateString() to .ToString("...")) and i did it in... 20min max (CTRL + SHIFT + F)

Comment: @psoshmo if the OP is not dealing with multi locale dates, i will recommend "my" option, if he deals with it or if he has some similar problem  where he needs to call a custom method, then i would recommend "yours"